# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException during execution of Contextloads() method in Spring Boot JUnit test case

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, testcase

We have a Spring boot v 2.7.x application, running on java 11. And we want to switch to java 17 and Spring boot 3.0.0.
But now, when I am making the changes locally (IDE is IntelliJ), the following test class:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

@SpringBootTest
class MyCompanyAppRegistrationApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

started failing with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@55a66bbf 

testClass = company.registration.MyCompanyAppRegistrationApplicationTests, 
locations = [], 
classes = [company.registration.MyCompanyAppRegistrationApplication], 
contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], 
propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], 
contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1e6cc850, 

                      org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@48b22fd4, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@178270b2, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@3d36dff4, 
                      org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@3954286c], 
resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [company.registration.MyCompanyAppRegistrationApplication]: Failed to load class [javax.servlet.Filter]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to load class [javax.servlet.Filter]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
```

Since Spring 3.x supports JakartaEE 9 and 10, I have changed all the needed packages from javax* to Jakarta.*. But obviously for some reason somewhere Javax.servlet.Filter is wanted.
Where I should look into this? Should I look at the dependencies in the pom file? The pom file looks like this:

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <commons-lib.version>3.2.1</commons-lib.version>
        <datasource-lib.version>1.4.0</datasource-lib.version>

        <wiremock.version>2.27.2</wiremock.version>
        <archunit.version>1.0.1</archunit.version>
        <guava.version>31.1-jre</guava.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>
        <jakarta.validaton.api.version>3.0.0</jakarta.validaton.api.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- internal dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my company</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my company</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasource-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${datasource-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--PROVIDED-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.validaton.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.archunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>archunit</artifactId>
            <version>${archunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0.2131</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>libs-staging-local</name>
            <url>https://some-url</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>libs-snapshot-local</name>
            <url>https://some-url</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>azd-releases</id>
            <url>https://some-url</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>azd-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://some-url</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: have you tried to check your dependency tree ? with `mvn dependency:tree`